# "build-essential" package needs "sudo apt upgrade" command execution?

Tags: apt

As I can see in the official [documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/InstallingCompilers), in order to install the package `build-essential` the execution of the commands below are needed:

```
$ sudo apt update
$ sudo apt upgrade
```

But I am wondering if the second one is in fact needed or not, as I think it is not related with the installation of this package. Or maybe the installation of the package updates (`upgrade` command) are needed because `build-essential` package depends on some of these other packages?

Comment: What's the downside of doing it anyway?

Comment: If you think it is an error, probably the best thing you could do is file a bug against it (https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu-docs).

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer they told me:

> Yes, while the second command not may be *needed*, it's wise (in order to prevent dependency issues) to run it before installing new packages.

So it is just for a **wise reason**.